# Is there a way to get the full http request in pycurl?

Tags: python, http, pycurl

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://httpbin.org/post')

post_data = {'field': 'value'}
# Form data must be provided already urlencoded.
postfields = urlencode(post_data)
# Sets request method to POST,
# Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded
# and data to send in request body.
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postfields)

c.perform()
c.close()
```

This is example from official doc.
I want to know what would be the http request looks like.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `VERBOSE` option, works like `curl -v`, will print request/response headers to `stderr`:

```
c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
```

see more detail on [pycurl doc](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/troubleshooting.html).